# Java Not Stopping to send Email (JAvaMail Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-mail

I am working on an Eclipse project. I was making a registration activation link but yet the Java mail is sending the message endless

Here is my method to send Email:

```
public static Mailer  sendMail(Mailer userActivation) {

        final String username = "harfrank2@gmail.com";
        final String password = "";password for the email

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

         String userEmail = userActivation.getActvEmail();
         String ActMessage = userActivation.getActLink();

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("harfrank2@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(userEmail));
            message.setSubject("E-Dealing Activation Link");
            message.setText("Dear "+userEmail
                + "\n\n You have a registered" 
                + ", Please Click the link bellow to activate your acoount"
                + "\n Product "+ActMessage
                    );

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
return sendMail(userActivation);    
}
```

Comment: what do you expect with this as return statement? return sendMail(userActivation); make it a void method and return nothing, or a boolean method that returns true on completion, or false on failure to send

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return sendMail(userActivation);
```

Will call the method infinitely. remove the recursion call and return proper mailer.

Comment: let me have your guidence sir

Answer (score 0):

```
//return userActivation object instead of returning sendMail(userActivation )

public static Mailer  sendMail(Mailer userActivation) {

        final String username = "harfrank2@gmail.com";
        final String password = "";password for the email

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

         String userEmail = userActivation.getActvEmail();
         String ActMessage = userActivation.getActLink();

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("harfrank2@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(userEmail));
            message.setSubject("E-Dealing Activation Link");
            message.setText("Dear "+userEmail
                + "\n\n You have a registered" 
                + ", Please Click the link bellow to activate your acoount"
                + "\n Product "+ActMessage
                    );

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

return userActivation;    
}
```